# Splitting an Access database and potentially creating duplicate records

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-office

I am wondering how Access works when two users go to create a new record on the same table using their local front end's, and what primary key (autonumber) they will get in return. Someone I work with has said that on their legacy DB,  they sometimes got duplicate unique keys (maybe it returned an error, I don't know). But how is this possible? or is it?

I've never used the legacy DB to witness this problem.

I can see how it may be possible in theory. Where a front end retrieves the next autonumber and before saving to the table(whilst filling out the form), the next user also retrieves the same autonumber. I cannot test this theory yet, but I would like to know how it truly works, how Access deals with this issue and whether this theory is nonsense or not.

I can try and clarify my problem further if required, but I hope I've explained well enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They will always get individual AutoNumbers assigned.

Comment: As I suspected. I am interested how it logically works though, i will have to look in to the communication between the front and backend